# Safe delete docker tmp folder

Tags: docker

I had to cancel a docker build 2 times during "uploading context" phase.
I figure out what I was doing wrong, but know I have some huge files in docker tmp folder.

Can I safely delete these folders? What about deleting the whole "/var/lib/docker/tmp" folder?

- /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder185153115/
- /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder737796513/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe to delete tmp folder.

But you will need to restart docker service afterwards